# can not create the python jupyter notebook (New Notebook is deactivated) in the dsx

Tags: data-science-experience, ibm-data-catalog

I can not create the python jupyter notebook (New Notebook is deactivated) in the dsx

But previously it was possible. Could you check this?

P.S. but when I created the project not with the cloud object but with the swift then also it was not possible to create the python jupyter notebook (New Notebook is deactivated) even at the first time. But at that time it was possible to create the python jupyter notebook in the cloud object project.

Why some function icons are deactivated? ex) + New flow in the SPSS Modeler flows, + New Model in the Models.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you check if you have an instance of "Data Science Experience" in your Apps and Services. Go to Profile (top-right) --> Settings --> Apps and Service. Under the Apps, there should be an app of the type "Data Science Experience".

Comment: Contact DSX support for these issues.

Comment: Hi @SumitGoyal Thanks to your comment after creating the dsx service it was possible to create. Thank you very much! But still I can not create the Data Flows. This one is still deactivated.

Comment: For data flows you need to provision data refinery service

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of "Data Science Experience" service before you can create notebooks in DSX. Please check if you have that in your Apps and Services. Go to Profile (top-right) --> Settings --> Apps and Service. Under the Apps, there should be an app of the type "Data Science Experience". If its not there create one from the IBM Cloud console: https://console.bluemix.net/ . Make sure you that in the correct Account and Org (same as your DSX account).